# Como puedo mostrar cada key de mi arreglo junto con su respectivo valor?

Tags: php, array

Tengo este arreglo, lo que quiero hacer es a cada valor obtener su key y su valor respectivos, alguna forma que pueda hacer esto?

Adjunto imagen del arreglo;[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que me haga un echo de cada key con su valor.

Algo como:

```
echo $clave . 'valor = ' . $valor;
```

Pero como es un arreglo no sé como podría mostrar esos valores en pantalla.

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recorriendo el array con `foreach`

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
{
  echo $key." valor = ".$value."<br>";
}
```

Comment: gracias funciono de maravilla :)